# Rails: How to add guest's name to nested form components?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

This is my first question on SO.  W00t!

As in this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised), I'm able to create a survey model and form which accepts accepts_nested_attributes_for questions, and the questions model accepts_nested_attributes_for answers.

If users are signed in, then I can associate their answers with their user_id.  However, I'd like to make it possible for guests to fill out this form too.  This would be a great way to lower the barrier to participation.

I'd like guest users to be able to add their name to the form so other users can distinguish between guests that have not yet created accounts.  To do that, I've created a guest_name field in the answer model.

The problem:  If they add their name to the form *after* they create new answers, how can I associate their name with their answer?

Inside surveys_controller.rb I am currently creating a variable called `@responding_user_id` and setting it to the signed-in user's ID or setting it to 0 if no one is signed in:

```
@responding_user_id = (current_user ? current_user.id : 0)
```

so that inside `answer.html.erb`, I can do this to associate the signed-in user's ID with his/her answer:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :user_id, :value => @responding_user_id %>
```

In the survey, users see multiple questions and they can add one or more answers to any question by clicking the "Add Answer" link from the partial called _question_fields.html.erb:

```
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
<%= render 'answer_fields', f: builder %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_fields "Add a New Response", f, :answers %>
```

I guess I could force them to input their name prior to adding answers and then change the hidden user_id fields through jQuery, but that is not an optimal user experience.

The only part of this that I'm having trouble with is assigning the guest name to the answer's hidden user_id field.  The reason this is difficult is that the HTML for the hidden field is generated when the user clicks "Add Answer" and at that point, they may not have entered their guest name yet.

Maybe the only way to do this is with jQuery as mentioned above?

Thanks!!

Comment: should be `@responding_user_id == current_user.id ? current_user.id : 0`, but it's weird to assign 0

Comment: Single equals sign is necessary, I believe, because I'm setting the value of the variable; I added parentheses above to make it more clear.  On your second point, I do agree it's weird to assign 0 as the user_id, but it seems to be helpful in this case because user_id is required and later I can search for answers from anonymous users if that is ever necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, here do you suppose to store the guest's names? You have just a `user_id` field. so you have to change your model.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, changing the model will be necessary to store a guest_name.  I'll update that in the question above.  But how does the guest_name get stored in the hidden field for user_id in the answer if the guest name is entered after the answer is filled in?

Comment: I think i didn't understand what the problem is, the guest user name you want to save is associated with the global survey or you have a sigle guest name for each answer (if so, i ask you why). If you have just one guest name for the entire survey you simple have to add something like `if !current_user f.text_field :guest name`, but i think i misunderstood your question

Comment: Hi @Vilelm I am hoping for a guest user to write their name in one time and it would apply to all the new answers they are providing.  In the Railscast at http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised all answers to a question are displayed in the form (even ones by other users).  But the only part of this that I'm having trouble with is assigning the guest name to the answer after the answer fields have already been generated by an "Add Answer" link that users can click multiple times to add multiple answers.

Comment: So it's a javascript-side task, because answers are added through a javascript function. I can reccommend you the nested_form gem from Ryan Bates https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form, which trigger a `nested:fieldAdded` event you can use to trigger an action which fill an hidden field when the event is rised. If this is the case i can update the answer with some example code.

Comment: Perfect!  I think that's what I'm looking for.  I accepted your answer, but I can't vote it up without more reputation points.  Thanks very much for the advice.